REST API in Java - How to support PATCH with Hibernate Validator
When writing a REST-API in Java, the PATCH method requests that a "set of changes" described in the request entity be applied to the resource identified by the Request-URI. (see: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5789)
Given following resource:
{
  productId: 7,
  name: "container",
  contactPerson: "peter",
  price: 12
}

With PATCH i should be able to set the "contactPerson" to NULL while not touching the other fields, like this:
{
  productId: 7,
  contactPerson: null
}

Within the Java Ecosystem how can i implement this in a good way, considering that the most relevant libraries here need to have full support for it:

Jackson (JSON Deserialization)
Hibernate Validator (Bean Validation)
Microprofile OpenAPI (API-Definition)

Java Optional
Among others i tried out Java-Optional, and while it initially seemed to work it is the wrong tool for this, as an Optional should not contain a NULL-Value, but it should also be possible to set a value to NULL explicitly within a PATCH (instead of omitting it).

but i did get very far with using Optional. The only problem was that Hibernate Validator did not supported it in the way i needed it.

For Example, the following looked good initially (here for the name-field which is required = false and nullable = false):
@Schema(required = false, nullable = false)
Optional<@NotNull @Size(max = 255) String> name = Optional.empty();

Hibernate validator considered the @NotNull Annotation to be violated when the name field was missing in the request, which i found strange because the annotation is within the Optional-Generic-Declaration (not directly on the Optional)
JsonNullable
Jackson provides a JsonNullable annotation. While this is the right tool for the task and is seemingly supported for openapi, it does not seem to be supported for hibernate validator, at least i could not find something about it.
Validation
Mostly the problem seems to be during validation of Bean Validation Annotations, which are important to have for an API.

When using annotations like @Size(255), @Email etc. there is the requirement that...

...those validations must be validated by the Hibernate Validator when the field is given/set in the PATCH
...those validations must not be validated when the field is omitted (missing) in the PATCH.



--
Is the REST-PATCH covered by those major libraries of the Java Ecosystem, and if yes, what is the recommended way to support it?

How about getting a key-value map in the request body, where the key matches the field name.
@PatchMapping("/boxes/{id}")
public Box patchBox(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Map<String, Object> values) throws JsonMappingException {
    return boxService.patchBox(id, values);
}

Then the case where the field value is null will not overlap with the case where the field is not present in the request, and you can use ObjectMapper to automatically update only those fields that came in the request.
@Override
@Transactional
public Box patchBox(Long id, Map<String, Object> values) throws JsonMappingException {
    Box box = entityManager.find(Box.class, id);
    objectMapper.updateValue(box, values);
    return box;
}

Of course, you can't validate the field values ​​from the request, but you automatically validate the entity whose fields are updated with these values. Ask yourself how you can validate a field value from the request if its correctness depends on the value ​​of another field that is not in the request.

Hello Andrey, thanks for sharing this pragmatic approach to the problem! In your approach it seems that the validation of the input data would be missing then, because you leave it up to the database to accept / not accept, which works for most annotations. Some edge-cases are: "email", "phone", "password" and like you stated: validations where fields depend on each other. Whats missing would be, to create a good openapi description. But maybe annotations can help here. Thanks for sharing, My mind really was stuck the last days with this problem, and your approach is some fresh view :)

i experimented with your approach (see my answer), and i think it is good enough that i can mark it as accepted answer. Thx again!

based on Andrey Smeliks approach, i have found some additional tweaks, that let me use OpenAPI and Hibernate Validator based on this approach in a way that i find ok.
Controller

Annotate the Controller for OpenAPI with the Pojo as Request-Body
Use a HashMap as Parameter (for modified-fields detection)
Convert the HashMap to a Pojo (with help of jackson)

    @Inject
    ObjectMapper jsonMapper;

    @PATCH
    @Operation(summary = "patch an existing product")
    @RequestBody
    @APIResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "product patch successful")
    @APIResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Server unavailable")
    @Path("/{productId}")
    public void patch(
        @RequestBody(description = "Patch Object (each field besides the productId is optional)!",
            required = true,
            content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
                schema = @Schema(implementation = UpdateProductRequest.class)))
        Map<String, Object> map
    ) throws ValidationException {
        UpdateProductRequest updateProductRequest = jsonMapper.convertValue(map, UpdateProductRequest.class);
        productManager.patch(new RequestContext(1, 1), map, updateProductRequest);
    }

Service/Manager

Given the Pojo and the HashMap, validate the Pojo, but only for the fields contained in the HashMap (Modified-Fields only!)
Update only the Modified-Fields into the Db (here done with jOOQ-Record which tracks modified-fields and only updates those when used in an update-statement)

    public void patch(
        RequestContext requestContext,
        final Map<String, Object> map,
        final UpdateProductRequest updateProductRequest) throws ValidationException {
        database1.dsl(requestContext).transaction(tsx -> {
            // Validate the API-Update-Model (but only for the fields present in the given hashmap)
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations = this.validator.validateProperty(updateProductRequest, entry.getKey());
                if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
                    throw new ValidationException(violations);
                }
            }

            // Put the changed-fields into the DB-Record of Jooq so the DAO only saves the changed fields to the DB.
            ProductRecord update = new ProductRecord();
            update.setProductId(updateProductRequest.productId());
            if (map.containsKey("price")) update.setPrice(updateProductRequest.price());
            if (map.containsKey("clientId")) update.setClientId(updateProductRequest.clientId());
            if (map.containsKey("typeId")) update.setTypeId(updateProductRequest.typeId());

            ProductDAO productDAO = new ProductDAO(tsx.dsl());
            productDAO.update(update);
        });
    }

